# Does there exist a matrix $A\neq I$ such that $A^n=1$ for any $n$?

Tags: linear-transformations

I wonder if there exists a matrix $A\neq I$ such that $A^n=1$ for any $n>1$ (positive I guess)? I think of rotation by $2\pi/n$, and the rotation matrix applied $n$ times gives the identity matrix?

Comment: Well, if $A \ne I$ and $A^n=I$ then $A^{n+1} = A \ne I$.

Comment: It cannot work for *any* $n$ (just choose $n=1$). Perhaps you meant  for *some* $n$?

Comment: Do you mean, for any $n>1$ there is matrix $A_n \ne I$ such that $A_n^n=I$? In that case, the answer is yes, for example $$A_n = \begin{bmatrix} \cos \frac{2\pi}{n} & -\sin \frac{2\pi}{n} \\ \sin \frac{2\pi}{n} & \cos \frac{2\pi}{n} \end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 4):

For all positive $n$ simultaneously  is impossible: for one
$$
A^1 \neq I,
$$
and also if $A^n=I$ for some $n \in \mathbb N$ then 
$$
A^{n+1}=A^n\cdot A=A\neq I.
$$

But if you want it to hold for some $n$ then the answer is yes:
$$
A= \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1  \\
1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix} \quad \text{and} \ A^n=I, \quad \text{for all even} \ n \in \mathbb N.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Yes, for every $n$, a rotation by $2\pi/n$ has the property that $A^n=I$.

In a certain sense this is the only solution: One can prove that if $A$ is a real matrix satisfying $A^n=I$, then $A$ is *similar* to a block diagonal matrix where each block is *either* a 2×2 rotation by some multiple of $2\pi/n$, *or* $I_{1\times 1}$, *or* (if $n$ is even) $-I_{1\times1}$.

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is the rotation by $2\pi/n$, then we indeed have $A\neq I$ and $A^n = I$.